# scraping data from table in node js

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am new in `web scraping` and trying to scrape data from a table using `puppeteer` in `node js`. I am using the class tag in each tr and td element and for paragraph tag also.

[image]

Comment: It's great that you are trying. Can you share your code so we can see what should be fixed?

Comment: please see attached image. we get this page after login.